# FFmpeg installation not detected with diart

Tags: python, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, openai-whisper, torchaudio

Here I'm using the [diart](https://github.com/juanmc2005/diart) library for audio transcription and the OpenAI Whisper model model.
When I run my code I get this error though

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vkyc/Desktop/projectRasa/audio/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/torchaudio/_extension.py", line 71, in _init_ffmpeg
_load_lib("libtorchaudio_ffmpeg")
File "/home/vkyc/Desktop/projectRasa/audio/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/torchaudio/_extension.py", line 52, in _load_lib
torch.ops.load_library(path)
File "/home/vkyc/Desktop/projectRasa/audio/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/torch/_ops.py", 
line 573, in load_library
ctypes.CDLL(path)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libavdevice.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vkyc/Desktop/audio_streaming/LiveStream.py", line 13, in <module>
from diart.sources import MicrophoneAudioSource
File "/home/vkyc/Desktop/projectRasa/audio/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/diart/sources.py", line 11, in <module>
from torchaudio.io import StreamReader
File "/home/vkyc/Desktop/projectRasa/audio/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/torchaudio/io/__init__.py", line 21, in __getattr__
torchaudio._extension._init_ffmpeg()
File "/home/vkyc/Desktop/projectRasa/audio/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/torchaudio/_extension.py", line 73, in _init_ffmpeg
raise ImportError("FFmpeg libraries are not found. Please install FFmpeg.") from err
ImportError: FFmpeg libraries are not found. Please install FFmpeg.
```

I tried `pip install python-ffmpeg` and`sudo apt install ffmpeg`.
Although FFmpeg is installed on my system it still throws the same error.

Comment: What version of ffmpeg do you have installed? You can check with `ffmpeg --version`

Comment: ffmpeg version 6.0

Comment: You can try to install `libavdevice58` from apt directly (but it should be installed automatically with `ffmpeg`).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/installation.html#optional-dependencies) the TorchAudio module supports FFmpeg version 4.1 - 4.4. If you build TorchAudio from the source FFmpeg 5 is supported.

Reinstall a supported FFmpeg version and then it should work. As you didn't provied any code I couldn't try it out though.